# Get the values of a SelectedItem in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox in a WPF Page each Item of which consists of two Labels. I have assigned them the names FirstName, LastName:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Name="FirstName" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Name="LastName" Text="{Binding LastName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

When the user selects an Item of the Listbox, I want to hold their values separately in order to pass them to another Page. I try to this end in the code behind the code:

```
 ListItemCollection lbi = List1.SelectedItem as ListItemCollection;

        string first = lbi.FirstListItem.DataContext.ToString();
        string last = lbi.LastListItem.DataContext.ToString();
```

However I get a nullReferenceException at the definition of strings? What is wrong in this way? How can I get the SelectedItem values?

**Update:** The Binding values derive from an SQLAdapter with a SQL Query. See the code behind:

```
SqlDataAdapter dAdapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr1, cnStr);

        DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet();
        dAdapt1.Fill(dataSet1);

        List1.DataContext = dataSet1.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Have you debugged this and stepped through to see what is null? If I had to guess I would say the cast of the selected item to ListItemCollection is returning null. Wouldn't the type of the selected item be ListItem?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is ListItem, but I want to get from it them two values (FirstName, LastName). This is waht I am searching for. I tried with ListItemCollection, it does not seem to work however.

Comment: What is the type of the elements stored in ListBox.ItemsSource? Can you extend your xaml snippet above to show how this is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DataTable and ListBox##

myDataSet.BookTable. firstColumn and lastColumn.

> binding ready

1.

```
adapter.Fill(myDataSet, "BookTable");
```

2.

```
myListBox.DataContext = myDataSet;
```

> binding begin

3.XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BookTable}"
```

4.
Window.Resources>

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BookItemTemplate">
                <Grid>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=first}" Grid.Column="0"/> 
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=last}" Grid.Column="1" />
```

5.

```
ItemTemplate ="{StaticResource BookItemTemplate}"/>
```

> **binding end**

6.

```
DataRowView d1=List1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
string first =d1["first"].tostring();
string last =d1["last"].tostring();
```

Comment: You got exactly what I wanted. Especially the line: DataRowView d1=List1.SelectedItem as DataRowView; is alone adequate for the solution of my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Andy has already commented, `List1.SelectedItem` is not a `ListItemCollection`, so you cannot cast to that type, hence `lbi` is `null`.

In the DataTemplate you're binding to properties `FirstName` and `LastName`. There must be a class that defines these properties, let's call it `Person`.

I guess the following, because you haven't shown it. You're binding the `ItemSource` of the ListBox to a collection of `Person` objects, provided by some property of the object that is returned by `dataSet1.Tables[0]` (because you set `List1.DataContext` to that value).

So what you would have to write to get the selected item is this:

```
Person lbi = List1.SelectedItems as Person;
```

and replace `Person` by whatever that type really is in your application.

Comment: Ok, but what would be the form of class Person in order to create Objects that hold the contents of SelestedItem? The problem is that I cannot "split" the SelectedItem into FirstName and LastName. This is the point of my question.

Comment: I case you can see a `FirstName`/`LastName` combination in the ListBox there must be an object that is the owner of these properties. There is one such "person" object per ListBox item. The type of the `SelectedItem` is the same as the type of the "person" object. Look into `dataSet1.Tables[0]` to find out what the type is.

Comment: @arjacsoh What type of item is stored in your `ListBox`? If it is a `DataRow`, then your `SelectedItem` will be a `DataRow.` If it is a `Person` class, then `SelectedItem` will be a `Person` class.