# When using ListBox in WPF, how to get access to the selected value(s) programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

In my code I'm using a list box to display objects from a class I'm creating.  What I want is to be able to click on an item in the list box and programmatically use the selected item.  The items come from a Dictionary as shown below.

```
private Dictionary<Int32, MyClass> collection;

public Window1()
{
    ListBox1.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(ClickAnItem);
    ListBox1.ItemSource = collection;
}
```

Now, this all works and the ListBox displays my collection like I would expect, and I have the event firing as it should, but I'm stuck on how to actually use the selected value.

```
private void ClickAnItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox list = sender as ListBox;
    /** list has the Int32 and the MyClass object but I can't seem to 
     *  get them out of there programmatically
     */
}
```

I've tried casting the ListBox.SelectedItems into an object of type Dictionary to no avail.

I didn't run it, but [here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239003/get-the-values-of-a-selecteditem-in-wpf) that seems similar. However, I would like to stay away from editing XAML if possible.  The more I can do at run-time the better.

So my question is, how do I get access to the 'Int32' and the 'MyClass' of the selected item?  I've used C# in the past but I'm just now jumping back into it and this has been bugging me for over an hour.

Comment: What is ClickAnItem?? how are you using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the value from the `SelectedItem` property on the ListBox and cast it to the appropriate type. In your case this will be a `KeyValuePair<Int32, MyClass>` as that is what makes up your `Dictionary`

Give this a try:

```
private void ClickAnItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ListBox list = sender as ListBox;

   var selectedItem = listBox.SelectedItem as KeyValuePair<Int32, MyClass>;
}
```

Comment: You were faster. I was about to post that too =)

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed.  I had looked into possibly making a Tuple but I wasn't aware of KeyValuePairs.